# How to set dynamic SMTP details laravel

Tags: laravel, smtp

I am working with a project where i need to update SMTP details on every admin login. I am storing the details in database, what is the best way to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My own approach: remove `Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class` from `config/app.php` list of providers loaded at bootstrap, and create a new middleware to load it manually after the user has been identified.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;  
use Illuminate\Mail\TransportManager;

use Closure;  
use Mail;  
use Config;  
use App;

class OverwriteMail  
{
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        /*
            $conf is an array containing the mail configuration,
            a described in config/mail.php. Something like:

            [
                'driver' => 'smtp',
                'host' => 'smtp.mydomain.com',
                'username' => foo',
                'password' => 'bar'
                ...
            ]
        */
        $conf = my_own_function();

        Config::set('mail', $conf);

        $app = App::getInstance();
        $app->register('Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Source: http://blog.madbob.org/laravel-dynamic-mail-configuration/

Answer (score 2):

I think this should answer your question:
https://laravel.io/index.php/forum/07-22-2014-swiftmailer-with-dynamic-mail-configuration

Just store it in a database table and use the `Config` facade to set the details on the fly.

Comment: Of course you have to adapt it for your needs, please post more details of your problem.