# laravel send mail from multiple smtp emails

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.7

I need to send mails from multiple mails 
Ex. `support@email.com`, `info@email.com`

in .env file I entered my default settings

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mymail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I use `markdown` email

```
public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.users.resetpassword',[
            'url' => url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', $this->token, false)),
            'user' => $this->notifiable,
            ]);
    }
```

this works fine

I try to change sender mail on the fly

```
Config::set('mail.encryption','ssl');
Config::set('mail.host','smtps.example.com');
Config::set('mail.port','465');
Config::set('mail.username','youraddress@example.com');
Config::set('mail.password','password');
Config::set('mail.from',  ['address' => 'youraddress@example.com' , 'name' => 'Your Name here']);
```

but it still sending from main account!!

how can I change the sender mail ?
thanks in advance

Comment: Because Laravel is configured to always read from the .env file first, and then the config arrays. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626492/how-to-set-dynamic-smtp-details-laravel

Comment: I use the same way to change locales and it works fine

Comment: That's because locales aren't defined in the .env file, but only in the config.

Answer (score 2):

You can override the config during runtime

```
use \Swift_Mailer;
use \Swift_SmtpTransport as SmtpTransport;

$transport = (new SmtpTransport(config('mail.host_other'), config('mail.port_other'), config('mail.encryption_other')))->setUsername(config('mail.username_other'))->setPassword(config('mail.password_other'));

$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);
Mail::setSwiftMailer($mailer);
Mail::send(...);
```

In your mail.php config file, add

```
<?php

return [
    ....
    ....
    'host_other' => env('HOST_OTHER'),
    'port_other' => env('PORT_OTHER'),
    'encryption_other' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION_OTHER'),
    'username_other' => env('MAIL_USERNAME_OTHER'),
    'password_other' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD_OTHER'),


    ....
    ....
]
```

Get more information here https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/sending.html